# Error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, 32-bit, c++

I am working with a Virtex-7 FPGA library (consisting of millions of .h, .cpp, etc. files) which was previously compiled by a Win32 platform, and I am now trying to build it for an x64 platform. But every time I face this error:

"error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'"

and this warning:

" warning MSB8028: The intermediate directory (x64\Release) contains files shared from another project (blablaAPP.vcxproj). This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior."

I made the "Include Directories" and "Library Directories" sections in "Properties\Configuration Properties\VC++ Directories" for the Active(x64) platform just the same as its Win32. I also went to "Properties\Linker\Advanced\Target Machine" and it was "Machine X64", but it didn't solve the issue. I am also using Visual Studio 2013 in Windows 10. Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is?

Cheers,

Nader